# How to place an event on an oracle table?

Tags: oracle

I am using an oracle SQL table and I want to basically put an event listener on the table. I want to be notified if the values of of particular rows/columns are updated from one value to another. I was looking in the oracle documentation and I did not see how to do this. These events should also account for new rows too. Is this possible? If so can anybody point me in the right direction to see how to do it? thanks.

Comment: Is your question somehow related to Microsoft SQL Server? Remove the `sql-server` tag if not or clarify your question accordingly.

Comment: Nope. Sorry I updated by removing the tag it is about oracle database.

Comment: Sounds like what you are looking for is a trigger (look it up).  But I'd seriously question the wisdom of "notifying" someone every time such a change is made to the table.  How do you see this notification taking place?  Email? SMS text?  During non-business hours?  I'd think someone is going to quickly tire of being buried in pointless notifications.